# maven unable to resolve dependency and cannot access jar

Tags: java, maven

I have my project dependencies in my `pom.xml` file and the required dependencies ( its another project ) jar has been available in `.m2` directory.

But when i do `mvn clean compile` am getting the below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies for project war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Cannot access pscs (http://demo01.corp.cat.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/) 
in offline mode and the artifact api-client:jar:1.0.282 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
```

But the same dependencies in some other project is working fine.

Comment: key phrase -- `same dependencies in some other project is working fine`. You might want to check the configuration of the other project as well

Comment: Not sure about what are the key configuration I have to check for this.. some basic configuration stuff I have to check

Comment: Manually go into the .m2 repository folder and check if the .jar file stated in the error message is there. If not, you can manually download it, place it into your .m2 folder and try again. Also check that your settings.xml is pointing to the correct repository folder.

Comment: @user3437460 - `.jar` is presented in .m2 folder and its working for other project dependencies only for specific project its not working and giving this error message.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Check your pom.xml for this project vs the project that you say works for the .jar file. Are both pom files pointing to the same version of the .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings.xml` file which is under `\.m2\settings.xml`. Then change property of `offline` mode to `true`.

```
<settings>
    ...

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            ...
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <offline>true</offline>
</settings>
```

After that everything should work, because Maven always tried to connect to central repository.

Comment: Its `true` only. Also, same dependencies working for other project. only for the specific project and getting this error.

Comment: if so, and this is so specific project, it is hard to guess what is this. show working and not working examples, and run commands.

Comment: Do we have any maven comments to check for project dependencies structure

Comment: yes, I use this https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/